# should I use await on return?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I have an MVC web application, the controller action calls a code in a business layer, which in turn calls an API:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAction(){
   Info something = await businessLayer.GetInfoAsync();
   return View(something);
}
```

in the business layer I have GetInfoAsync defined as follows:

```
public async Task<Info> GetInfoAsync(){
   return await myLib.GetAsync<Info>();
}
```

in my library I have GetAsync defined as follows:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync(){
   //do something
   var data = await aService.Get<T>();
   return data;
}
```

As you can see above GetInfoAsync method just makes a call to myLib.GetAsync and returns whatever value myLib.GetAsync returns. 
Could I just get rid of async/await for GetInfoAsync, and define it as follows :

```
public Task<Info> GetInfoAsync(){
   return myLib.GetAsync<Info>();
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (and should) get rid of `async`/`await` in the middle layer.

If your `async` method is just `await`ing a single task (and that's all it does), then the `async` just adds overhead.

Comment: thank you ! btw, your blog posts on async/await stuff has been very helpful to me. Thanks alot !